# Debug button not working! (Visual basic express 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, vb.net-2010

The debug button in visual basic doesn't run the program that I developed.

I tried:

- Changed to expert mode --> changed to exceptions thrown in MDA
- Couldn't find the program that runs it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure that your project is set as the StartUp project. Right click on the project in the solution explorer and click, "Set As Start Up Project." If this does not solve your problem, try to Clean and Build your solution by either right clicking on the solution or by going to the Build menu item at the top of Visual Studio.